# Flash object's size doesn't match the on screen size

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created a small tile 64x64 for testing my tile engine and it is added like so in the loop

```
var grass:Grass = new Grass();
grass.x = (x * TILE_SIZE);
grass.y = (y * TILE_SIZE);
grass.width = TILE_SIZE;
grass.height = TILE_SIZE;
container.addChild(grass);

public class Grass extends MovieClip {

public function Grass() {
    // constructor code
    this.width = 64;
    this.height = 64;
}
}
```

If i trace out the .width and .scale of my object they match the code as 64x64 and a scale of 1. But when i print screen the screen in the debugger and measure in Photoshop they are 94x84 and I can find out where it is going wrong?

Anything I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: is this for a mobile device, by any chance

Comment: have you checked the scale of container ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assure stage scale mode is not scaling:

```
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your debugger streches your flash video to fullscreen, which would stretch your grass object out. A screenshot would help.

Answer (score -1):

Is this actionscript3? where is the declaration of the Grass class? there can be some error with it

Comment: Yes, sorry it is actionscript 3. To create it I just drew a rectangle on the stage and converted it to a symbol with the class

`public class Grass extends MovieClip {
  
  
  public function Grass() {
   // constructor code
   this.width = 64;
   this.height = 64;
  }
 }`

I have just noticed when i drag the Grass object onto the scene from the Library it is the correct size, but the ones drawn through code are still incorrect